# Adding a character that deletes previous characters.in a string

Tags: vb.net, string, character

Are there characters that can delete other characters in a string in vb.net?

Example:

```
Dim del_char = "character that deletes previous string"
Dim str = "My Name"
Dim str2 = "Sinomra"

Dim new_str = str & del_char & str2
'so the result of the new_str should be "Sinomra"
```

Comment: No.  I can only assume that what you have shown is a contrived example.  What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: There is a method from luxand's face sdk where it gets a string for the file name.

Here is a snippet of the code:
`Dim TrackerMemoryFile = "tracker.dat"`
`FSDK.LoadTrackerMemoryFromFile(tracker, TrackerMemoryFile)`

I tried `"..\tracker.dat"` and it stored the file on the previous folder. But what I really want is to store the file on a specific folder like C:\MyTrackerFolder.

_I really am bad at explaining things. lol_

Comment: Either you are indeed very bad at explaining things or you're missing the bleeding obvious.  If you want to save to a file in a specific folder then why not just provide the path to that folder and file?

Comment: I'm really bad at explaining. haha. I can't provide the path because the `FSDK.LoadTrackerMemoryFromFile` method saves the data in the `ApplicationStartup & \tracker.dat`. What I'm trying to accomplish is that i want to delete the whole value of the `ApplicationStartup` then provide another path. Example: `ApplicationStartup & character_that_deletes_previous_string & "C\:MyTrackerFolder\tracker.dat"`